# Windows 10 SplitView + Pivot not working properly

Tags: pivot, win-universal-app, splitview

I have used `SplitView` in my *Windows 10 Universal Application* and I added pivot to the `SplitView`.Content

Problem is when I start the application I cant click on *Pivot* headers to navigate.

This problem is occurring on *Phone* only *Desktop* or tablet not showing this issue.

If I Click on Hamburger Menu to open `SplitView`.Pane and then close the Pane I can touch the pivot headers and navigate pivot items.

Why my Pivot headers are not clickable at the start?

```
<SplitView>
<SplitView.Content>
    <Pivot>
        <PivotItem />
        <PivotItem />
        <PivotItem />
    </Pivot>
</SplitView.Content>
<SplitView.Pane>
    Hamburger Menu Button
    Other Buttons
</SplitView.Pane>
```

Comment: I have tested it in my side, I can click the Pivot header to navigate at the start. So it will be better if you can give a reproduced project in here.

Comment: Did you check it on both desktop and phone? Because I am having problem with phone. It might be because of insider preview on phone. Please reply if you checked it on phone...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi i have the same issues when i was using spiltview + pivot in UWP

```
<SplitView>
     <SplitView.Pane>
      <!--  your view left bar view here -->
     </SplitView.Pane>
      <!-- remove your splitView.content tag then put your frame here -->
       <Frame x:Name="SplitViewFrame"/>
</splitView>
```

then set your select values like

```
SplitViewFrame.Navigate(typeof(your pivot page));
```

now it will be work

Answer (score 0):

I am currently having the same issue. Clicking on the pivot header doesn't change the content of the pivot body. We need to resize the app so that the content of the selected pivot is shown. I have the sample and video showing the issue:

http://1drv.ms/1M7jYTQ

It happens on both, the phone and computer.